# Partial correlation vs conditional correlation?

Tags: correlation

I have been taught about the partial correlation coefficient.

I later read that there is alao such a thing as a conditional correlation coefficient, **and that these are not the same.**

**What is the difference between the two?**

Comment: Although, the term "conditional correlation" is not explicitly mentioned there.

Comment: Welcome to CV Programmer2134. Your question would be a smidge improved if you could edit it to provide example formal definitions or formal use of both partial correlation & conditional correlation, and/or a link (e.g., Wikipedia) to a reference on each.

Comment: Answer for the conditional correlation part of the Q here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372386/when-are-correlated-normal-random-variables-multivariate-normal/372643#372643